# Lifting problem like Hensel's Lemma

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime number and let  $n$ be such that $p^k \nmid n$. Prove: If the equation $y^n\equiv a \pmod {p^k}$ has a solution with $\mathrm {gcd} (y,p)=1$, then for every $m>k$, there is a solution for the equation $y^n\equiv a \pmod {p^m}$.

This is a problem from an introductory course in number theory, and is in the Hensel's Lemma section, which contains the generalized version where $p^l$ can divide the derivative if $2l< k$ . I tried to modify the proof for Hensel's Lemma, but I couldn't deal with the lack of the above hypothesis.

Comment: Try induction.  if you have a solution $y_0 \pmod {p^k}$ try to find one $\pmod {p^{k+1}}$ by writing $y=y_0+tp^k$ and try to solve for $t$

Comment: That's what I was trying, but putting $y^n \pmod {p^{k+1}} I get $a\equiv y_0^n + ny_0^{n-1}p^{k}t \pmod {p^{k+1}} where $p$ may divide $n$.

Comment: Ah, right. And of course, not all solutions lift.  For instance, $2^3\equiv 17\pmod  {27}$ but none of the lifts, $2,11,20\pmod {27}$ will work.  Of course $5^3\equiv 17\pmod {27}$ and that's the point.  Instead of lifting by adding $tp^k$ add $tp^r$ for $r<k$.

Comment: Yes, proving Hensel's Lemma we take $r=k-l$ where $p^l$ is the greatest power of $p$ that divides $f'(y_0)$ for $f(x)=x^n-a$. But it's where I use the condition $2l<k$.

Comment: Yes...not sure how to cope with high powers of $p$ in $n$.  Is it true?

Comment: Yes. That's the problem on my approach.

Comment: I mean, have you tried numerically?  It's not obvious to me that the claim is true.    we have $2^9\equiv 8 \pmod 9$., yes?  But there is no solution to $x^9\equiv 8 \pmod {27}$ (unless I messed it up).

Comment: I guess in your example $p^k=9\mid n=9$. But yes, I haven't tried many numerical examples.

Comment: Wait, since you are assuming that $p^k$ doesn't divide $n$ then the partial lift should work.  The non-vanishing term is $ntp^l$ .  Take the greatest non-vanishing order.  if $v_p(n)=a<k$ then take $l=k-a$.

Comment: Why does the other terms vanish?

Comment: Yeah, there is still stuff to prove,  I'd try examples to see if it is plausible that all the higher terms vanish.  Even if they don't, maybe you can get a handle on what they look like.